# dynamic sub categories not displaying properly

Tags: php

I have a side-nav in my website that I want to display a list of categories and sub categories dynamically from my DB. I've got my categories to display properly as list items but my sub categories do not display the right way. Right now its only displaying the sub-categories in the bottom most category instead of displaying a list in each category drop-down. I've tried putting the sub_category function in the DELIMETER but that didn't work and I've looked at other questions but none seem to fit with what I need. So my question is how do i format this so that each category displays a list of sub-categories?
Here is my code for the functions:

```
    function get_categories(){
      $query = query("SELECT * FROM categories");
      confirm($query);

      while ($row = fetch_array($query)) {
        $category_links = <<<DELIMETER
        <li><a href="category.php?id={$row['cat_id']}" >{$row['cat_title']}</a>
        <div class="megadrop">

    DELIMETER;
    echo $category_links;
      }
}


    function get_sub_categories(){
      $query = query("SELECT * FROM sub_categories");
      confirm($query);

      while ($row = fetch_array($query)) {

        $category_links = <<<DELIMETER
        <li><a href="sub_categories.php?id={$row['cat_id']}" >{$row['sub_title']}</a></li>
    DELIMETER;
    echo $category_links;
      }

    }
```

And here is the side-nav page:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <ul class="menu">

    <?php  get_categories();?>

        <div class="col">

          <ul>
            <?php      get_sub_categories(); ?>
            </li>

          </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I am pretty sure the DELIMITER; needs to be in the very first column of the code. Maybe it is and StackOverflow just formatted it for you.

Comment: Also, where you have your while loop, inside is $category_links. Right now it is overwritten every loop. You should change the = to .= to append to it every iteration of the loop. That may be your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gandalf, it cannot work the way you want it to since you're running these two loops one after the other instead of intertwined.

What this does is essentially:

```
> get_categories()
<ul class="menu">
  <li> __CAT0__
  <li> __CAT1__
  <li> __CAT2__
  ...
    <div class="col">
      <ul>
        <li> __SUBCAT0.0__
        <li> __SUBCAT0.1__
        <li> __SUBCAT1.0__
        <li> __SUBCAT2.0__
        ...
```

Do you see how it's flawed? The answer lies in creating a proper data type which is capable of representing the nested structure you're after (what you most certainly want is a multi-dimensional array).

So let's see what we can do:

```
<?php

function get_sub_categories() {
   $categories = [];

   $query = query("SELECT * FROM sub_categories");
   confirm($query);

   while ($row = fetch_array($query)) {
     $parent = $row['parent_id'];
     $categories[$parent][] = $row;
   }

   return function($parent) use ($categories) {
     return isset($categories[$parent])
       ? $categories[$parent]
       : [];
     };
   };
}

function get_categories(){
  $categories = [];

  $query = query("SELECT * FROM categories");
  confirm($query);

  $findSubCategoriesFor = get_sub_categories();

  while ($row = fetch_array($query)) {
    $id = $row['cat_id'];

    $categories[$id] = [
      'category' => $row,
      'children' => $findSubCategoriesFor($id),
    ];
  }

  return $categories;
}
```

All you need to properly render the multi-leveled navigation, now, is to call `get_categories()` and render each entry one by one with nested loops (i.e. category -> children, category -> children ...)